# Weighted average in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I need to weight a variable by another in Power BI. I have tried several formulae that I have found online to no avail. The results are incorrect when I compare them with the SPSS output that I got previously. What could be the problem?

One of the variables I need to weight is:

Percentage of your new full-time entry-level college hires typically come from interviews initially conducted on-campus

And it needs to be weighted by:
Total number of new college graduate hires at organization

Could you please help?

Thank you!

[Here is a small sample of the data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYvAX.png)

Here is a small sample of the data:

Total   //  Percentage
242.00  //  80.00
2214.00 //
1613.00 //
371.00  //  60.00
382.00  //
0.00    //  15.00
120.00  //
400.00  //  15.00
104.00  //  40.00

And here is the expected output (as per SPSS):

Statistics
Percentage of your new full-time entry-level college hires typically come from interviews initially conducted on-campus
N   Valid   1117
Missing 4329
Mean        46.36